# Geographic coordinates from mapquest to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, coordinates, spreadsheet, mapquest

We're building a narrative map such as [these](http://atlascine2.classone-tech.com/), for academic as well as causual purposes. The data (location, type of location, time and coordinates) are stores in a Google Spreadsheet. Our objective is to have users fill in a form, to populate the dataset, instead of entering the data directly into it. This part works fine.

My biggest issue currently is to automatically geocode the locations sent in by the form.

I'm not a developer and I spent several days to fix this, to no avail.

The code (taken from [Bogdan Rau's blog](http://bogdanrau.com/blog/using-google-maps-apiv3-and-google-spreadsheets-part-ii) and modified) is the following (for latitude only):

```
function LatRange2(range) {
  var n = range.length;
  var m = range[0].length;
  var LLArray =new Array(n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    var fullAddress =" ";
    for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      fullAddress = fullAddress + " " + range[i][j];
    }

      var Url = 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=HIDDEN_KEY&inFormat=kvp&outFormat=json&location=' + fullAddress + '&thumbMaps=false';
      var Results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url);
      var lat = Results.lat;

      }
    LLArray[i] = new Array(1);
    LLArray[i][0] = lat;
  }
  return LLArray;
}
```

Because I was attempting too many geocodings (after a few tries, I was blocked for the day), I switched from the Google Geocoder to the MapQuest API. Also, the Rau's code was giving my wrong longitudes.

Now, the function returns an empty cell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

If the address you are geocoding is not in the OSM data, then you will get an empty response.  But most valid addresses should not return an empty cell.

```
http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=KEY&location=Denver,CO&callback=showit
```